# Does ReactiveMongo handle extended JSON to BSON conversion fully?

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, reactivemongo-play-json

I have been trying to use reactivemongo to insert some documents into a mongodb collection with a few BSON types.

I am using the Play JSON library to parse and manipulate some documents in [extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#bson.Date), here is one example:

```
{
    "_id" : {"$oid": "5f3403dc7e562db8e0aced6b"},
    "some_datetime" : {
        "$date" : {"$date": 1597841586927}
    }
}
```

I'm using `reactivemongo-play-json`, and so I have to import the following so my `JsObject` is automatically cast to a reactivemongo `BSONDocument` when passing it to `collection.insert.one`

```scala
import reactivemongo.play.json.compat._
import json2bson._
```

Unfortunately, once I open my mongo shell and look at the document I just inserted, this is the result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f3403dc7e562db8e0aced6b"),
    "some_datetime" : {
        "$date" : NumberLong("1597244282116")
    },
}
```

Only the `_id` has been understood as a BSON type described using extended JSON, and I'd expect the `some_datetime` field to be something like a `ISODate()`, same as I'd expect to see `UUID()`-type values instead of their extended JSON description which looks like this:

```
{'$binary': 'oKQrIfWuTI6JpPbPlYGYEQ==', '$type': '04'}
```

How can I make sure this extended JSON is actually converted to proper BSON types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is that what I thought to be extended JSON is actually not; my datetime should be formatted as:

```
{"$date": {"$numberLong": "1597841586927"}}
```

instead of

```
{"$date": 1597841586927}
```

The wrong format was introduced by my data source - a kafka connect mongo source connector not serializing documents to proper extended JSON by default (see [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64123986/the-official-mongodb-kafka-source-connector-does-not-publish-clean-extended-json/64123987#64123987)).