# The official MongoDB Kafka source connector does not publish clean extended JSON

Tags: mongodb-kafka-connector

I've setup a pretty simple [mongo kafka source connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/master/kafka-source/) to stream mongo's oplog to kafka. However, I see that in the messages published by the connector, the serialized oplog events do not respect the [extended JSON spec](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/); for instance, a datetime field is represented as:

```
{"$date": 1597841586927}
```

When the spec says it should be formatted as:

```
{"$date": {"$numberLong": "1597841586927"}}
```

Why am I not getting clean extended JSON?

*Note*: my connector config file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "mongosource",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": 1,
    "connection.uri": "...",
    "topic.prefix":"mongosource",
    "database": "mydb",
    "copy.existing": true,
    "change.stream.full.document": "updateLookup",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default json formatter of the source connector is a legacy one (see [this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/KAFKA-99) on the connector's JIRA project).

From version `1.3.0` of this connector, there's a new config option that you can add to ask the connector to output proper extended JSON:

```
"output.json.formatter": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.json.formatter.ExtendedJson"
```